# Saving a file on Windows Phone 8.1 (mobile IE)

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, windows-phone-8.1, mobile-safari

I'm developing a web application where one may save some configuration data into a json file on the computer. My approach works fine on desktop browsers (IE11, Chrome, FF) and also good on an tested Android device. In mobile IE on WP8.1 there happens nothing and on iOS devices the file is shown rather than downloaded. Here is my code:

```
var saveToFile = function () {

    var a       = document.createElement("a"),
        blob    = new Blob([getUserConfigs()/*get json from somewhere*/], {type:"application/json"}),
        fName   = "fileABC";

    //check for MS IE FileAPI
    if (window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {
         a.onclick = function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fName);
        };
    //otherwise use HTML5 Standard
    } else {
        a.setAttribute("href", window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
        a.setAttribute("download", fName);

        a.onclick = function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        };
    }

    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);
};

$("#saveBtn").click(saveToFile);
```

What's missing? How could I get this to work on mobile IE/Safari? On desktop this works fine. Thanks for any help :)